# Does KL divergence keep order under convolution?

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, convolution, information-theory

Suppose there are three random variables $X,Y,Z$ such that $$D_{KL}(X,Y)\leqslant D_{KL}(X,Z)$$ And there is an independent (with respect to $X,Y,Z$) Gaussian noise $\xi\sim N(0,1)$. Can we say the following?

$$ D_{KL}(X+\xi,Y+\xi)\leqslant D_{KL}(X+\xi,Z+\xi) $$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: The distribution of $X+\xi$ is a convolution.

Comment: If you can show us what you tried, we will be able to better guide you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true.

---

The first reason to expect that this doesn't hold is that one can get a sort of free pass due to the infinitude of KL divergence between discrete and continuous laws. So if we make the law of $Z$ discrete, but the law of $X$ to be a slightly smoothened version of this, and the law of $Y$ very different from that of $X$, but smooth, then after smoothing with the Gaussian the order of KL divergences could well be flipped. We can execute this idea somewhat more simplistically.

Recall that the fact that $D (\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_1^2)\|\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_2^2)) = \frac12\left( (\sigma_1/\sigma_2)^2 - 1- \log (\sigma_1/{\sigma_2})^2\right)$ in nats (i.e., where the log in the definition of $D$ is natural).  I'll use $\gamma$ to denote the standard Gaussian law.

Let $s > 1$ be a parameter we will fix later. Take $P, Q$ to be centred Gaussians of variance $1$ and $s - 1$, and $R$ to be the point mass at $0$.

We have $D(P\|Q) < \infty = D(P\|R)$. But $P*\gamma = \mathcal{N}(0,2), Q*\gamma= \mathcal{N}(0,s),$ and $R * \gamma = \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. In this case, we get $$ D(P*\gamma\|Q*\gamma) = \frac12 \left( \frac2s -1  - \log \frac2s \right), \\ D(P*\gamma\|R*\gamma) = \frac12\left( 2 - 1 - \log2 \right).$$

But notice that the first expression above blows up as $s \to \infty,$ meaning that large $s$ yield a counterexample to the original statement.

---

We can also make this example nondegenrate, relying basically on the fact that $D$ blows up to $\infty$ smoothly as $\sigma_2 \to 0$. Indeed, parametrise the variances of $Q$ and $R$ as $s-1$ and $r$, where $s > 1, r < 1$. Then we have the conditions $$ \frac1{s-1} - \log \frac1{s-1} < \frac 1r - \log \frac1r\\  \frac2s - \log \frac2s > \frac2{r+1} - \log \frac2{r+1},$$ and we want to check if this has solutions $(r,s)$. For this, essentially any tiny $r,$ and somewhat large $s$ will work, but we can be more explicit: take $r = 0.5, s = 3$ (which I found with a CAS). We have $$\frac{1}{2} + \log(2) - (2 - \log(2)) = 2 \log(2) - 3/2 < -0.1\\ \frac23 - \log \frac23 - \left( \frac43 - \log \frac43  \right) = \log 2 - \frac23 > 0.02,  $$ where I'm using the standard fact that $0.69 < \log(2) < 0.7.$

Comment: Excellent counterexamples! I found another one. D(N(0,1), N(1,144))=1.99<2=D(N(0,1), N(2,1)) while D(N(0,2), N(1,145))=1.6>1=D(N(0,2), N(2,2)). Besides, what is CAS?

Comment: Yeah I think even in the Gaussians, there should be a whole blob of counterexamples (seen as a subset of the parameter space $(\mu_P, \sigma_P, \mu_Q,\sigma_Q, \mu_R, \sigma_R)$). It'd actually be interesting to figure out exactly what this set is etc., do try if you have the time. CAS is just computer algebra system (i.e., I found the points numerically, in this case using wolfram alpha).